# CSS - alinha images

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte codigo HTML:

```
<div class="book">
            <div class="book-image">
                <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $books->Image ).'"height="180" width="130">'; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="book-values">
                <span><label for="ISBN">ISBN:</label> <?php echo $books->ISBN;?></span><br>
                <span><label for="title">Title:</label><?php echo $books->Title;?></span><br>
                <span><label for="author's name">Author's name:</label><?php echo $books->Authorsname;?></span><br>
                <span><label for="edition">Edition:</label><?php echo $books->edition;?></span><br>             
                <span><label for="year">Year:</label><?php echo $books->year;?></span><br>
                <span><label for="category">Category:</label><?php echo $books->category;?></span><br>
                <span><label for="publisher">Publisher:</label><?php echo $books->publisher;?></span><br>
                <span><label for="quantity">Quantity-in-stock:</label><?php echo $books->quantityinstock;?></span><br>
                <span><label for="price">Price:</label><?php echo $books->price;?></span><br>
                <span><a href="shoppingcart.php?ISBN=<?php echo $books->ISBN; ?>">Order Now</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Em CSS:

```
.book{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;  
}

.book-image{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 150px;
    text-align:center;
}

.book-values{
    padding-left:20px;
    float: right;
    display: block;

}
```

No entanto as imagens não estao alinhas(ver foto).eu preciso alinhar para que fique melhor a nivel estetico[image: livros]

Comment: já tentou utilizar as propriedades de position? uma dica é trocar a div principal por <li> visto que tem 4 imagens, seriam 4 li com width igual e position relative, poe os 4 dentro de uma div tipo mask com width desejado e as li ficam com width de 50%

Comment: O ideal seria você postar o código renderizado aqui.

Answer (score 2):

Bom vamos lá, acho que o problema está naquela tag div no meio do nada, mas reparei que no div principal, você deu um float left, isso vai acabar quebrando o layout pois todos os elementos dessa div irão querer ficar ao left, assim que sobrar um espaço entre eles ele irá jogar para a esquerda, uma solução para isso
seria você criar outra div para ser a div pai, ou seja os livros serão exibidos dentro dela, fiz o seguinte, Criei a div e dei a classe "exibição", com a classe definida, no css dei um display flex, para os elementos serem flexiveis e flex-direction: row para se comportarem em linhas, flex-wrap: wrap para as linhas se quebrarem quando atingir um tamanho width: 100% e height: auto, vale lembrar que essa estilização é na div principal que no caso é a exibicao... Segue o exemplo no jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kec1x4zm/ caso fiquem um embaixo do outro aumente o tamanho da tela de resultado, fiz a quebra por questões de responsibilidade

```
<div class="exibicao">
 <div class="book">
            <div class="book-image">
                <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $books->Image ).'"height="180" width="130">'; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="book-values">
                <span><label for="ISBN">ISBN:</label> <?php echo $books->ISBN;?></span><br>
                <span><label for="title">Title:</label><?php echo $books->Title;?></span><br>
                <span><label for="author's name">Author's name:</label><?php echo $books->Authorsname;?></span><br>
                <span><label for="edition">Edition:</label><?php echo $books->edition;?></span><br>             
                <span><label for="year">Year:</label><?php echo $books->year;?></span><br>
                <span><label for="category">Category:</label><?php echo $books->category;?></span><br>
                <span><label for="publisher">Publisher:</label><?php echo $books->publisher;?></span><br>
                <span><label for="quantity">Quantity-in-stock:</label><?php echo $books->quantityinstock;?></span><br>
                <span><label for="price">Price:</label><?php echo $books->price;?></span><br>
                <span><a href="shoppingcart.php?ISBN=<?php echo $books->ISBN; ?>">Order Now</a></span>
            </div>

  </div>
 <!-- Uma tag div foi removida daqui -->
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não colocou no código mas acho que o que está quebrando a formatação é o título "List of Book", tente usar o atributo **clear: both;** no css desse título.